# Embedding or attaching a picture when cataloguing sound FX

Tags: cataloguing, library, file-naming, file-organization, database

Is it possible to embed / attach a jpg file (or any picture file format for that matter) to a WAV file?  I read somewhere ages ago that you can but have been unable to remember where.  I'm in the process of cataloguing a batch of recordings and was wondering if I should just include a photo I have of the location (which I thought might be useful) in a folder with the relevant WAV files or whether there's a more permanent way of linking the two.  Does anyone else do anything like this when they're cataloguing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Soundminer](http://www.soundminer.com/SM_Site/Home.html) - it lets you assign image data when cataloging audio files, and then recalls that image in a sidebar when said audio comes up in a search. Definitely a handy feature for anything you may want a visual reference of later.

Comment: Thanks for that - I'm just about to upgrade from Miniminer anyway so I'll check that out.